# Filed to create query for method public abstract

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I created a login user using controller, user, repository and service in my project. In controller, if email id and password are not null then login otherwise throw an exception "User Not Exist". I am getting the bellow error, can you help me to fix this issue?

Error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'registrationRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.adventure.network.model.User com.adventure.network.repository.RegistrationRepository.findByEmailIdAndByPassword(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)! No property byPassword found for type User!
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private RegistrationService service;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public User loginUser(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
        String tempEmailId = user.getEmailId();
        String tempPassword = user.getPassword();
        
        User userObject = null;
        if(tempEmailId!=null && tempPassword!=null) {
            userObject = service.fetchUserByEmailIdByPassword(tempEmailId, tempPassword);   
        }
        if(userObject == null) {
            throw new Exception("User is not exict");
        }
        return userObject;
    }
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class RegistrationService {

    @Autowired 
    private RegistrationRepository repo;
    
    public User fetchUserByEmailIdByPassword(String email, String password) {
        return repo.findByEmailIdAndByPassword(email, password);
        
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface RegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    public User findByEmailIdAndByPassword(String emailId, String password);
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.adventure</groupId>
    <artifactId>network</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>network</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Rename method `findByEmailIdAnsByPassword` to `findByEmailIdAndPassword`

Comment: Oh,  Thanx it got fixed after changing findByEmailIdAnaByPassword to findByEmailIdAndPassword. The method can be any name why my method name was getting error?

Comment: Not in the repository. Spring parses method name of repository class to understand which properties of `User` class to use for search. That is how JPA repository works in spring boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your error message `No property byPassword found for type User!`, it is looking for the property named `byPassword` you need to change to `andPassword` in the repository as shown below.

```
public interface RegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    public User findByEmailIdAndPassword(String emailId, String password);
}
```

Spring will parse every property mentioned after by, you need by only at the start of the method

You can also change the name to be more readable as

```
public interface RegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    public User findUserByEmailIdAndPassword(String emailId, String password);
}
```